# Unable to connect to oracle database using jdbc thin drivers

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I am trying to connect to Oracle 10 XE database using Oracle thin drivers but I'm unable to achieve this. I even added the drivers to my classpath during compilation.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Connectivity {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.setProperty("user", "SYSTEM");
        props.setProperty("password", "iiita");

        try {
            Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,props);
        String sql ="select sysdate as current_day from dual";

        PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

        ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println("Current Date from Oracle : " +  result.getString("current_day"));
        }

        System.out.println("done");

    }
}
```

This code gives the following error during running

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:644)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:202)
    at Connectivity.main(Connectivity.java:16)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to specify the ojdbc14 classpath when running the main class:

For Windows: `java -cp .;<path>/ojdbc14.jar Connectivity`

On Linux:    `java -cp .:<path>/ojdbc14.jar Connectivity`

P.S. You don't need ojdbc14.jar on your classpath to compile the main class. It's a runtime dependency.

Comment: Error: Could not find or load main class Connectivity

Comment: Are your running the command from the same directory where Connectivity.class is placed?

Comment: What I'm doing locally. I have the following directory structure: _connectivity (Connectivity.class, Connectivity.java)_. _connectivity_ is a directory.

_Connectivity.java_ is exactly the same as you posted above (the package is empty).

Then I run from connectivity directory:
_java -cp .;<path>/ojdbc14.jar Connectivity_,

where _<path>/ojdbc14.jar_ is an absolute path to Oracle JDBC 1.4 driver jar.

Everything works fine

Comment: I think you are running it on Windows. I just changed ';' with ':' and it worked successfully on Linux

Answer (score 3):

Add this line before your call to `getConnection(url, props)`

```
Class.forName ("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

It isn't enough to have the jars on your classpath unless they are jdbc driver > 4.0 version. You have to actually register the driver with the `DriverManager`.

Change `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE` to `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:XE`. I believe this is the new syntax.

Compile as

```
javac -classpath /<your_path>/ojdbc6.jar Connectivity.java
```

Run as

```
java Connectivity
```

Comment: the same problem still persists after modification

Comment: my jdbc driver is ojdbc14.jar

Comment: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver tried this too still no success

Comment: javac -classpath /home/khirod/Downloads/ojdbc14.jar Connectivity.java

I think this is the right way to do it I have done the same. Plz correct me if I'm wrong but I'm new to Java on linux

Comment: If the class wasn't in the classpath, a `ClassNotFouncException` would be thrown, not a `SQLException`

Comment: Download and use `ojdbc6.jar`. Depending on your java version, `ojdbc14.jar` (java 1.4) might not work anymore.

Comment: Last ditch effort, change `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE` to `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521:XE`

Comment: I think there is some problem with latest java7 version & the old Oracle XE 10g database I'm trying to use. Maybe Oracle 11g will work. Thanks for your help